# How to pass context data to an another file as a dict/list/any format in django?

Tags: python, django

In my project I'm trying to scrape reviews of a car chose by user. In the django app I want to pass the data in the context dictionary to an another `scrape.py` file.
Code:
**models.py**

```
class SelectCar(models.Model):
    BRANDS = (
        ('BMW','BMW'),
        ('MR','Mercedes')
    )
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                  choices=BRANDS,
                  default="BMW")
    CAR_MODELS = (
        ('X1','X1'),
        ('X2','X2'),
        ('X3','X3')

    )

    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                  choices=CAR_MODELS,
                  default="X1")
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import SelectCar

class SelectCarForm(forms.ModelForm):
  
    class Meta:
        model = SelectCar
        fields = '__all__'
```

**scrape.py**, here i want to import the context data and choose the url for the specific car in an if-else chain. For example, if chose car is honda amaze, context should be imported into `scrape.py` such that I'm able to choose url.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
"""import context here in some way"""

def happyScrape():

    """here, import the context and choose url based on chosen car
    if car is Honda amaze, choose url for honda amaze and so on.
    example- if brand is honda and model is amaze, 
    """
    url = 'https://www.carwale.com/honda-cars/amaze/user-reviews/'\
   


    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
    cw_result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    cw_soup = BeautifulSoup(cw_result.text, 'html5lib')



    scrapeList  =[] 

    #scrape code here, stored in scrapeListHTML

    for data in scrapeListHtml:
        scrapeList.append(data.text)


    with open(r'./scrape/scrapeListFile.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in scrapeList:
            # write each item on a new line
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import SelectCarForm
def ScrapeView(request):

    
    context = {}
    context['SelectCarForm'] = SelectCarForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'run_script' in request.POST:
        from .scrape import happyScrape

        happyScrape()       
        
    return render(request, "scrape.html", context)
```

**EDIT**
solved it by passing data to happyScrape() itself in the form of brand, car_model as the answer said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the specific data from the `context` in the `happyScrape()` function.

In `scrape.py`

```
def happyScrape(data):

   # use this data here
   ...
```

In `views.py`

```
def ScrapeView(request):

   ...
   
   happyScrape(<data_from_context>)
   
   ...
```

Comment: How do i import the context to ```scrape.py``` file?

Comment: I don't think it imports on its own

Comment: You cannot import the context, but you can pass the data to the method as 
an argument. 
You've already used happyScrape() inside ScrapeView, why don't you just pass the required data to it and use it inside the happyScrape method?